# Bootstrap nav-stacked dropdown to the right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an interface with twitter-bootstrap that has a sidebar for navigation, hence nav-stacked. I also want to use a dropdown menu from some of the tabs. I find it inelegant that the dropdown menu drops down on top of all of the other menu items. I'd like for the dropdown menu to drop down off to the side of the side-bar so you can still see the rest of the sidebar items. I looked into pull-right, but I don't think that's what I am looking for.

Anyways, here is what I have so far:

```
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked"> 
                <li class="{{home}}">
                    <a href="/home/">Home</a></li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/cars/">Cars<b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="{{1999s10}}"><a href="/cars/1999s10">1999 Electric S-10</a></li>
                        <li class="{{1965malibu}}"><a href="/cars/1965malibu">1965 Malibu</a></li>
                        <li class="{{1960hearse}}"><a href="/cars/1960hearse">1960 Hearse</a></li>
                        <li class="{{1966gto}}"><a href="/cars/1966gto">1966 GTO</a></li>
                        <li class="{{1971blazer}}"><a href="/cars/1971blazer">1971 Bazer</a></li>
                        <!-- <li class="divider"></li> -->
                    </ul>

                </li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want a dropdown-menu that is not acting like a dropdown-menu :) It is fairly easy to accomplish, here your working example on a "fresh" twitter bootstrap

```js
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked" style="width:200px;">  <!-- <<<< added styling -->
    <li class="{{home}}"><a href="/home/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/cars/">Cars<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="margin-left:200px;margin-top:-38px;">  <!-- <<<< added styling -->
            <li class="{{1999s10}}"><a href="/cars/1999s10">1999 Electric S-10</a></li>
            <li class="{{1965malibu}}"><a href="/cars/1965malibu">1965 Malibu</a></li>
            <li class="{{1960hearse}}"><a href="/cars/1960hearse">1960 Hearse</a></li>
            <li class="{{1966gto}}"><a href="/cars/1966gto">1966 GTO</a></li>
            <li class="{{1971blazer}}"><a href="/cars/1971blazer">1971 Bazer</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <!-- dummy extra links -->
    <li class="{{home}}"><a href="/home/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="{{home}}"><a href="/home/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="{{home}}"><a href="/home/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="{{home}}"><a href="/home/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="{{home}}"><a href="/home/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="{{home}}"><a href="/home/">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Just style `dropdown-menu` so it is positioned off the `nav-tabs` and the `dropdown-toggle` element vertically. I cannot know what width you are using, so i have set the `nav-tabs` to 200px.

Comment: You have an extra " in your answer on line 4.

Comment: @MITjanitor, this was an old answer :) Thank you, have corrected it.